# Proper way to start exercising after long gap

Tags: strength, beginners

I am 5'7" tall and my weight is 80 kg. As you can guess, I am fat. I have lots of fat.

At one point of time (2016) I wasn't very fat (68 kg) and I was able to perform 10 pull ups, 35-40 push ups, and could squat and bench 50 kg (excluding the bar weight) for 10-12 reps.

Starting from 2017 or so, I turned alcoholic after moving to a cold hilly place, and have never worked out much since then. Maybe occasionally I would walk like 2 kms or perform bench/military. It was always for short duration to show any results. I have got weaker and also suffer from occasional backaches, waist pain, or neck pain. I can't do even a single pull up now. I can still do 15 push ups.

I am 27 years old now and I have realised staying fat is detrimental and I have to reduce my weight. Since January of this year I have stopped taking alcohol. I have to start exercising now to get stronger and lose some fat.

It so happens that gyms are closed in my place and may remain closed till it's safer. I have borrowed a long bar, an EZ bar, a bench and few plates from a friend.

May I have some advice on:

Simple home workout using the above mentioned equipment, and bodyweight movements?

Thanks in advance for your time.

---

Update:

I have started exercising. At present my routine looks like this:

> 5 AM: Walking around the house multiple times (~700-1000 metres); everyday
>
> 9 AM: Squat and bench press (30 kg, 3 sets, 10-15 reps); two days a week. Started last week. I plan to stick to it for two months.
>
> 6 PM: Walking again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many congratulations on your decision to stop drinking and to lose weight. You are very young and it's great decision!

Regarding the exercise, you have to consider that exercise is medicine! When I was 22 I had panic attacks and exercise saved my life. It is an excellent stress reliever and a confidence booster!

As you experience some myosceletical pain, you should first advice a physician. Though you can start really light cardio and weights. You can start walking more at an easy pace (not running as you have back pain). With the equipment you have I should suggest some front squats (better posture and better for your back pain) only with the bar (maybe 15 reps, 3 sets). Also, you could do some bodyweight good mornings to strengthen your back and planks to strengthen your core. You can do deadlifts (very light) and row with the bar for your back. For your neck, you can lay down facing the ceiling, lift your neck and do some rotations (left to right or up and down) of your head. You can also do some crunches, mountain climbers, lunges etc. On this stage you have to prepare your neural system first and then strengthen the muscles. Then pushups (on excellent form) and some negative pull-ups. Sidekicks, and sitted military press with good back support. Squats (without weight).

What you need is consistency and a mindset that exercise is not a sprint but a marathon through years and years, and a health booster not an ego booster.

Wish you all the best!

Comment: Thanks for your time, encouragement, and your kind words. Can you please advise me on the new details that I added now?